# How to handle editing of dates in input React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, luxon

I am building a form in React that contains an `input` of type `"date"`. What is the correct way to handle a backspace/edit to the input? For example, when the state is the date `12/12/1212`, and I press backspace on the input, it reverts to an empty input.

The state is:

```
{
  ...,
  date: new Date(),
}
```

The state change handler looks like:

```
const handleDateChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  setState({ ... state, date: value });
}
```

The input is:

```
<input
  type="date"
  name="date"
  value={DateTime.fromJSDate(newOverride.date).toFormat(
    "yyyy-MM-dd",
  )}
  onChange={handleNewInputChange}                                   
/>
```

In essence, I want to be able to delete/edit the date, without clearing the whole thing and starting again. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle the format error, you need to pass back the exact edit value instead of a parsed one back to the input value.

I used moment for parsing if a date string is in a valid format, display input in red background if not valid, hope you get the idea.

```
const Datepicker = () => {
  const [state, set] = useState();

  const parsed = moment(state, "YYYY-MM-DD", true);
  const error = !parsed.isValid();

  return (
    <input
      type="date"
      name="date"
      value={state}
      onChange={(e) => set(e.target.value)}
      style={{ backgroundColor: error ? "red" : undefined }}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use type="date", the browser expects the input value to be in the format "YYYY-MM-DD".If the provided value doesn't match this format, it defaults to an empty string.

```
import { DateTime } from "luxon";

const handleDateChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  const { name, value } = event.target;

  const dateObject = DateTime.fromFormat(value, "yyyy-MM-dd").toJSDate();

  setState({ ...state, date: dateObject });
};

<input
  type="date"
  name="date"
  value={DateTime.fromJSDate(state.date).toFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")}
  onChange={handleDateChange}
/>
```

By applying this code, when users press backspace or edit the date, the handleDateChange function will correctly convert the input value to a Date object and update the state accordingly and allowing users to modify the date without clearing the entire input.